# Why is MVC Controller "return Redirect" decoding my encoded double quotes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that redirects the user. I append a querystring to the URL, but I noticed that the final URL in the browser is decoding my double quotes. So, it shows double quotes in my URL. Is there a way to keep the URL Encoding so it shows %22 instead?

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Search") + "?t=%22test%22");
```

The url in the browsers shows ?t="test". Anyone know why this is happening? I tried to double encode it, but that created an error message. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using RedirectToAction?

Comment: Why do you need it to stay encoded? Browsers are allowed to show what they want as long as they send the data properly encoded when needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Search",new {t= "%22test%22" }) );
```

this will create `URL` like this `%2522test%2522` here `%25` means `%` so in action you can do

```
string str="%2522test%2522" //you will get this from URL
var value= HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str));
```

i used `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` two times because first time it will give `%22test%22` and second time when decoding `%22test%22` you will get `"test"`.